# ls: <filename>: Cannot allocate memory

Tags: cyanogenmod, insufficient-memory

I'm having out of memory problems with `rsync` in CYM11. However, I realized now that the problem is more serious. For some files, when I simply try to list one single file with name `somefilename` in the terminal emulator, I get:

```
 $ ls somefilename
 ls: somefilename: Cannot allocate memory
```

If I do `ls` over the `somefilename` parent folder (with 30 files only), I see several files but not `somefilename`.

But then, after a wile, the error is gone...

Clues? Maybe a card problem?

Thanks!

L.

PS: [rant] I'm having too many problems with CYM11! [\rant]

Comment: My first guess would be a bug in the memory management in the OS. Are you using a nightly? Have you tried a different nightly or a more stable build?

Comment: I'm honestly at the stage of "CyanogenMod, there's your problem" and the frequency of this is increasing. Maybe another ROM would be an idea, or as Dan said something more stable. (I know they do great work, but I've never tried a build that didn't have something preventing it being a daily driver on ANY device)

Comment: @DanHulme: Yes, I'm using a nightly for the Galaxy Note (n7000). I cannot use a stable build, unless I go back to 10.1.3, since there are no M builds for the N7000.

Comment: No wonder you're having too many problems then. Nightly builds are not intended for everyday use.

Comment: @RossC: Indeed, that's my experience too. Unfortunately, I've experienced several problems with Cyanogenmod, and there is very little support (I've never able to get ANY answer from Cyanogenmod website). Not sure if any other ROM is better, though....?

Comment: @DanHulme: But then, which would be a solution? No M builds for the Note, it seems that device has been completely abandoned. I just upgraded to the last nightly, and the problems persist.

Comment: @RossC I know people who use stable builds on popular devices without problems. It's just that porting ROMs is hard, and there aren't enough people willing to lend a hand.

Comment: @DanHulme yep as I said they do some great work but are really up against it at every turn. Nightly build are a no no for sure, unless you're testing for them

Comment: Maybe some of you can point me to a better maintained custom ROM, at least for the Galaxy Note? CYM11 clearly sucks on it.

Answer (score 0):

Cyanogenmod 11 is extremely buggy on the Galaxy Note I (N7000), and this seems to be one more of its bugs. I solved it by reformatting the card to `ext4` (reformatting to `exfat` didn't solve the problem).